# How do I retrieve data from Oracle as a query result using an anonymous PL/SQL block in Python?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

All the examples of using PL/SQL I can find end up looking like this ([this example taken from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL#Cursor_FOR_loops)):

```
FOR RecordIndex IN (SELECT person_code FROM people_table)
LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RecordIndex.person_code);
END LOOP;
```

In other words, they all have one thing in common: when it comes time to actually output the data somewhere, they stick it in `DBMS_OUTPUT`, which seems to be a pretty useless place for an application to process it.

If I wanted to retrieve data from an Oracle database using a PL/SQL feature as if this data were the result of a plain SQL query, how would I do it?  For example, if I wanted to process the rows deleted by a `DELETE ... RETURNING ... INTO` SQL statement in the same way that I would process the results of `SELECT ... FROM ...`?

I do not want to modify the schema of the database or create any stored procedures; I'd just like to do `cursor.execute("begin; ... something; end"); results = cursor.fetchall()`.

Particularly, I do *not* want to create a variable with `cursor.var()`, since that API is not portable between database implementations.  (Obviously the SQL won't be portable either, but it's a generally accepted fact that one needs to generate custom SQL strings for different database backends no matter what.)

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle 12c you will be able to define a temporary PL/SQL function *and* use it in a SELECT statement:

```
WITH FUNCTION x(param)
  <body>
END x;
SELECT x(p) FROM t
```

This is **one** SQL statement, a select from which you can fetch rows in the usual way.
Unfortunately Oracle 12c has not been released yet...

Comment: I'm still interested in older versions of Oracle, but it's good to know that this is coming.

Answer (score 1):

The "temporary table" idea in Oracle is a bad one.  They are not like  temporary tables in SQL*Server or Sybase.  In Oracle, the table is PERMANENT; only the content is temporary.
So you should not be writing an application which requires dynamic creation / deletion of tables - you will run into all sorts of problems following that approach.

Answer (score 1):

With OCI you can retrieve only table of simple types, not table of record

with cx_Oracle (Python):

```
cx = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn)
cu = cx.cursor()
dates = cu.var(cx_Oracle.DATE, 100)
cu.execute("""
DECLARE
  TYPE date_tab_typ IS TABLE OF DATE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_dates date_tab_typ;
BEGIN
  SELECT SYSDATE-ROWNUM BULK COLLECT INTO v_dates
    FROM user_objects
    WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
  :1 := v_dates;
END;
""", [dates])

dates = [dates.getvalue(i+1) for i in xrange(100)]
```

I've written a library which generates such anonymous PL/SQL blocks around stored functions/procedures to be able to use arrays of record types (you need to create an array per column in the record) - works, but not nice.

Or If you can't use cursors as a return type (because you cannot produce the records as a select), than you can write PIPELINED stored functions: they work like Python generators, produce one record per PIPE call!

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements were:

- **I do not want to modify the schema of the database**
- **or create any stored procedures** ... **Particularly, I do not want to create a variable with cursor.var()** *(Unfortunately, stored procs is the usual way to do it)*

You also asked in a comment how you'd create a temporary table that will be destroyed at the end of the transaction, I'll give you an example (since I think this is the only way to do it that will satisfy your requirements).

[**There are the usual caveats about this not handling errors or being bullet proof, but if you really want to proceed this way, this should get you started**]

```
import cx_Oracle

def main():
    block = """
        BEGIN
            -- you could put your PL/SQL in here, 
            -- to insert values into this table
            INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('test', 'this');
        END;
    """

    conn = cx_Oracle.connect("User/password@somewhere")
    curs = conn.cursor()
    conn.begin()
    curs.execute("""CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE some_table (
                        col1 VARCHAR2(10), 
                        col2 VARCHAR2(10)
                    ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS""")
    curs.execute(block)
    curs.execute('SELECT * FROM some_table')
    print(curs.fetchall())
    curs.execute('TRUNCATE TABLE some_table')
    curs.execute('DROP TABLE some_table')
    conn.commit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Returns:
[('test', 'this')]

Oracle [Global Temporary Table Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10595/tables003.htm) here.

Comment: My understanding is that DDL statements (like 'create table') implicitly commit the transaction in Oracle, so I can't create these on the fly.  I really just want per-transaction (or better yet, per-cursor) state to facilitate sending out these rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DBMS_SQL package in anonymous block to describe you query

```
    q="""DECLARE
  c           NUMBER;
  d           NUMBER;
  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  f           BOOLEAN;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  col_num    NUMBER;
  v_sql dbms_sql.varchar2a;
 v_sql_1 varchar2(32767);
 v_sql_2 varchar2(32767);
 v_sql_3 varchar2(32767);
 v_sql_4 varchar2(32767);
  v_type VARCHAR2(32):='';
  PROCEDURE print_rec(rec in DBMS_SQL.DESC_REC) IS
  BEGIN
    v_type:=CASE rec.col_type
                WHEN 1 THEN 'VARCHAR2'
                WHEN 12 THEN 'DATE'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'NUMBER'
            ELSE ''||rec.col_type
            END;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec.col_name||':'||rec.col_max_len||':'||v_type);
  END;
BEGIN
  v_sql(1):='%s';
  v_sql(2):='%s';
  v_sql(3):='%s';
  v_sql(4):='%s';
  v_sql(5):='%s';
  c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, v_sql,1,5,False, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);
/*
 * Following loop could simply be for j in 1..col_cnt loop.
 * Here we are simply illustrating some of the PL/SQL table
 * features.
 */
  col_num := rec_tab.first;
  IF (col_num IS NOT NULL) THEN
    LOOP
      print_rec(rec_tab(col_num));
      col_num := rec_tab.next(col_num);
      EXIT WHEN (col_num IS NULL);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
END;
/
""" % (qry[0:32000].replace("'","''"),qry[32000:64000].replace("'","''"),qry[64000:96000].replace("'","''"),qry[96000:128000].replace("'","''"),qry[128000:160000].replace("'","''"))
    regexp=re.compile(r'([\w\_\:\(\)\d]+)')
```

after this step you can create SQL statement and run the extract using SQL*Plus

Check [extractor.py](https://github.com/alexbuz/Oracle-To-Redshift-Data-Loader/blob/master/dist-64bit/include/extractor.py) for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in 2 ways:
1. Not portable- write into global context.
2. Portable-write into temporary table.

Comment: Please give examples of these. How do I write to the global context? How do I create a temporary table which will be destroyed at the end of the transaction?

Comment: For that matter, what *is* "the global context"?  When you say "not portable", what is it not portable to?  I'm just asking about Oracle here; in every other database, I can simply issue a 'select' and the results show up on the application's cursor.